# $window.print() generates multiple of the same sheets in different previews

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, printing

Using `$window.print()` in an angularjs project on a popup modal.  In the print preview in firefox, 3 of the same exact pages show up... and in chrome, 2 of the exact same pages.

Can someone explain why that is happening?

Comment: on successive calls, do those numbers increase? Have you bound inadverently the event handler more than once...?

Comment: @Stuart The numbers stay consistent on successive calls unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that when I was printing the modal the underlying page below the modal was also being chosen to be printed.  Even though in the print preview it showed multiple instances of the modal it was actually trying to print the content in the main page.  Solved with a media query to hide the main page on print.

I found this out because safari actually opens up the underlying page in the print doc.